# Mono (mod_mono) & Apache (httpd) on Fedora 10: failing to start correctly

Tags: mono, apache, mod-mono, xsp

It seems I am one of the few trying to get Mono's mod_mono to run on httpd on Fedora 10.

Mono is installed and the httpd is configured to use mod_mono.conf

But when I do this:

```
service httpd start
```

I get this error:

```
Starting httpd: [crit] (13)Permission denied: 
Failed to attach to existing dashboard,
and removing dashboard file '/var/run/mod_mono_dashboard_XXGLOBAL_1' failed 
(Permission denied).
```

When I  do this:

```
xsp
```

I get this error:

```
At System.OutOfMemoryException:.ctor (string), offset 0x18
Addr: 0x7f8e73d6e150
Callee: System.SystemException:.ctor (string)
**
ERROR:tramp-amd64.c:99:mono_arch_patch_callsite: code should not be reached
Stacktrace:

  at System.OutOfMemoryException..ctor (string) <0xffffffff>
  at System.OutOfMemoryException..ctor (string) <0x00018>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) System.Object.runtime_invoke_void__this___string (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

        /usr/lib64/libmono.so.0 [0x34f1a76812]
        /lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x315180f0f0]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x3150c32f05]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x183) [0x3150c34a73]
        /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_assertion_message+0x113) [0x34f125d7f3]
        /usr/lib64/libmono.so.0 [0x34f1a9e7a8]
        /usr/lib64/libmono.so.0 [0x34f1a7d080]
        [0x7f8e741d016e]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================

Aborted
```

Linux version:

```
Fedora release 10 (Cambridge)
```

Apache (httpd) version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.11 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar  6 2009 09:12:52
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:21
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.3, APR-Util 1.3.4
Compiled using: APR 1.3.3, APR-Util 1.3.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Mono version is 2.4 and Mono -V gives me this:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 2.0.1 (tarball)
Copyright (C) 2002-2008 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC)
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
```

Please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to install again mono, mod_mono, xsp form distribution, then
from source using 2.2, 2.4 and svn.

The problem is with the kernel 2.6.24-23-xen present on both servers. It
has a bug that has been fixed in the following versions . The problem is
the 64bit XEN kernel does not honour the MAP_32BIT flag.

And to add insult to injury, i cannot upgrade the kernels because it's a
VPS and i cannot install kernels.

Answer (score 0):

The first error you're getting is a known issue that shouldn't affect you. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985323/modmono-apache-failed-to-create-shared-memory-segment-for-backend/1027327#1027327).

As for the second error, shouldn't you be using "xsp2" instead of just "xsp"?

If that doesn't work, I would suggest you rather just try and install the latest Mono build from source. There are [instructions here](http://blog.ruski.co.za/page/Install-Mono-on-Ubuntu.aspx) for Ubuntu, but it should be similar enough for you to follow.